# Poor Call Quality using Twilio Programmable Voice SDK

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, heroku, twilio

I am upgrading my Twilio-enabled app from the old SDK to the new Twilio Programmable Voice (beta 5) but have run into several problems. Chief among them is poor audio quality of outgoing calls, in what can only be described as what lost packets must sound like. The problem exists even when I run the [Quickstart demo app](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-objc), leading me to the conclusion the problem rests in my Twiml. I've followed the instructions to a "T" with respect to setting the appropriate capabilities, entitlements, provisioning profile and uploading the voip push credential, but with little documentation on the new SDK or for Python versions of the server, I'm left scratching my head.

The only modifications to the demo app I've made are to include the "to" and "from" parameters in my call request like so:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"To" : self.phoneTextField.text, @"From": @"+16462332222",};
[[VoiceClient sharedInstance] configureAudioSession];
self.outgoingCall = [[VoiceClient sharedInstance] call:[self fetchAccessToken] params:params delegate:self];
```

The call goes out to my Twiml server (a python deployment on Heroku) at the appropriate endpoint as seen here:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.jwt.access_token import AccessToken, VoiceGrant
from twilio.rest import Client
import twilio.twiml

ACCOUNT_SID = 'ACblahblahblahblahblahblah'
API_KEY = 'SKblahblahblahblahblahblah'
API_KEY_SECRET = 'blahblahblahblahblahblah'
PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID = 'CRblahblahblahblahblahblah'
APP_SID = 'APblahblahblahblahblahblah'

IDENTITY = 'My_App'
CALLER_ID = '+15551111' # my actual number

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/makeTheDamnCall', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def makeTheDamnCall():
    account_sid = os.environ.get("ACCOUNT_SID", ACCOUNT_SID)
    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY", API_KEY)
    api_key_secret = os.environ.get("API_KEY_SECRET", API_KEY_SECRET)
    CALLER_ID = request.values.get('From')
    IDENTITY = request.values.get('To')
    client = Client(api_key, api_key_secret, account_sid)
    call = client.calls.create(url=request.url_root, to='client:' + IDENTITY, from_='client:' + CALLER_ID)

    return str(call.sid)
```

The console outputs `outgoingCall:didFailWithError: Twilio Services Error` and the call logs show a completed client call. An inspection of the debugger shows `TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record`. As you can see, the url I include in the request might be problematic as it just goes to the root but there is no way to leave the url blank (that I have found). I will eventually change this to a `url=request.url_root + 'handleRecording'` for call recording purposes but am taking things one step at a time for now.

My solution so far has been to ditch the `call = client.calls.create` in favor of the `dial` verb like so:

```
    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.dial(number = IDENTITY, callerId = CALLER_ID)
    return str(resp)
```

This makes calls, but the quality is so poor as to render it useless. (10+ seconds of silence followed by intermittent spurts of hearing the other party). Using the dial verb in this way is also unacceptable because of its inefficiency as I'm now billed for two calls each time.

The other major problem, which I'm not sure is connected or not, is the fact that I haven't yet been able to receive any incoming calls, though I suspect I may need to ask that question separately.

How can I get this line to work? I'm looking at you, @philnash. Help me make my app great again. :)

```
call = client.calls.create(url=request.url_root, to='client:' + IDENTITY, from_='client:' + CALLER_ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry it's taken me a while to get back to your question.

Firstly, the correct way to make the ongoing connection from your Programmable Voice SDK call is using [TwiML `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial). You were [creating a call using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), however you will have already have created the first leg of the call in the SDK and the TwiML forwards onto the second leg of the call, the person you dialled. Notably, you are billed for each leg of the call, not for two calls (legs can be of different length, for example, you could put the original caller through a menu system before dialling onto the recipient).

Secondly, regarding poor call quality, that's not something I can help with on Stack Overflow. The best thing to do in this situation is to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide some Call SIDs for affected calls. If you can [record an example call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-record) that would help too.

Finally, I haven't seen if you've asked another question about incoming calls yet, but please do and I'll do my best to help there. That probably is a code question that we can cover on SO.

Comment: Thanks Phil! I've opened a ticket with Twilio and included a Call and Recording SID.

Comment: I just spent 8 hours today finally getting https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial working, and I'm shocked at how bad the quality was. It's not usable for my paying customers. I've opened a support ticket.

Comment: Hi Ryan, glad to hear you opened a support ticket. Hopefully the team can look into whatever caused poor quality for you and get that solved.

Comment: hi @philnash as i am making call from sub account using rest api as a result i am getting different Call Sid which is child leg i assumed. as parent call sid and child leg sid is different from each other i am unable to record call using rest api. how can i make call from sub account in a effective way without changing leg so that i can record call also. please let me know. i am using quickstart voice swift. TIA

Comment: Hi @A_Rush, I'm afraid I'm going to need more context than that and a comment is not the best place to answer. Could you ask a new question with as much detail as possible and then send me the link?

Comment: sure. i am doing it now.